# How to call function after change input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-input, angular1.6, onfocusout

Using Angular 1.6

I´m trying to call some function like `$scope.myFunction` after change inputs

My code look like this

```
<md-input-container class="col-sm-12 md-block no-left-padding">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input name="name" ng-model="name" onfocusout="myFunction()">
</md-input-container>
```

I´m getting this error when I unfocus the input

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onfocusout
```

Comment: function is a reserve keyword in javascript, can you try with different name and check?

Comment: Sorry @Bhavesh, I gave the name "function" as an example, I have changed it to "myFunction" to prevent confusions

Answer (score 0):

`onfocusout` behaves similar to `onclick` - it is standard JavaScript callbacks.
To call function from scope/controller you need `ng-*`, probably you will be happy with `ng-blur`